# Empty Set Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that the empty set is a subset of every set.

I don't really know where to start other than the fact that I know a symbolic representation 
of the empty set and that it is included in every set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of $A\subseteq B$ is that, for every element $x\in A$, it follows that $x\in B$ as well.  Since the empty set has no elements, this is true vacuously.

Comment: Similarly, all Unicorns have 2 horns. Proof: let A = the set of all Unicorns, and B be the set of animals with two horns.